# include(page) function for script not loading DOM references

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-apps-script, google-sheets, dom

Using Google Apps Script HtmlService class to produce some output. This specific case is for a Google Sheets sidebar, but I'm also running into it when utilizing as a web app.

I'm running into an issue where if I put my script directly into the html file, the DOM references work fine. Once I put them into and  scriptlet, it throws an error;

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'value')

Here is the html form and scriptlet:

```
<body>
  <?!= include('LOGO') ?>
  <form id="add">
    <div><input id=" fName" type="text" /> First Name</div>
    <div><input id="lName" type="text" /> Last Name</div>
    <div><input id="empId" type="text" /> ID#</div>
    <div><input id="job" type="text" /> Job</div>
    <div><input id="wage" type="text" /> Wage</div>
    <div id="job2" type="text" style="display: none"><input id="jobtwo" type="text" /> Job 2</div>
    <div id="wage2" type="text" style="display: none"><input id="wagetwo" type="text" /> Wage 2</div>
    <div id="job3" type="text" style="display: none"><input id="jobthree" type="text" /> Job 3</div>
    <div id="wage3" type="text" style="display: none"><input id="wagethree" type="text" /> Wage 3</div>
    <div>
      <button id="enter" type="button" onclick="addRecord()"> Enter</button>
      <button id="more" type="button" onclick="moreJobs()"> + Job</button>
      <button id="less" type="button" onclick="lessJobs()"> - Job</button>
      <button id="close" type="button" onclick="closeSide()"> Close</button>
    </div>
  </form>

  <?!= include("AddEmpJS") ?>
</body>
```

This is the AddEmpJS.html referenced by the include function;

```
<script>
    function addRecord() {
      let fname = document.getElementById("fName").value
      let lname = document.getElementById("lName").value
      let empId = document.getElementById("empId").value
      let job = document.getElementById("job").value
      let wage = document.getElementById("wage").value
      let job2 = document.getElementById("jobtwo").value
      let wage2 = document.getElementById("wagetwo").value
      let job3 = document.getElementById("jobthree").value
      let wage3 = document.getElementById("wagethree").value
      let record = [
        fname, lname, empId, job, wage, job2, wage2, job3, wage3
      ]
      console.log(record)
      google.script.run.addEmpRecord(record);
      document.getElementById("add").reset()
    }

    function moreJobs() {
      if(document.getElementById("job2").style.display == "none") {
        document.getElementById("job2").style.display = "block"
        document.getElementById("wage2").style.display = "block"
        return "job 2 showing"
      }
      if(document.getElementById("job3").style.display == "none") {
        document.getElementById("job3").style.display = "block"
        document.getElementById("wage3").style.display = "block"
        return "job 3 showing"
      }
    }

    function lessJobs() {
      if(document.getElementById("job3").style.display == "block") {
        document.getElementById("job3").style.display = "none"
        document.getElementById("wage3").style.display = "none"
        return "removing job 3"
      }      
      if(document.getElementById("job2").style.display == "block") {
        document.getElementById("job2").style.display = "none"
        document.getElementById("wage2").style.display = "none"
        return "removing job 2"
      }
    }

    function closeSide() {
      google.script.host.close()
    }

   </script>
```

The include function on the server side,

`function include(page) { return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(page).getContent(); }`

The UI that calls the sidebar,

```
function addEmp() {
  var page = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("AddEmp").evaluate();
  page.setTitle(" Add Employee")
  ui.showSidebar(page)
```

and the whole script,

```
const ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("EMPLOYEES");
const setup = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("SETUP");
const summary = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("SUMMARY");
const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

function onOpen(e) {
  ui.createMenu(" Employees")
    .addItem(" Add Employee", "addEmp")
    .addItem("✨ Edit Employee", "editEmp")
    .addItem(" Del Employee", "delEmp")
    .addToUi();
  ui.createMenu(" Departments")
    .addItem("➕ Add Department", "addDept")
    .addItem(" Edit Department", "editDept")
    .addItem("➖ Del Department", "delDept")
    .addToUi();
  ui.createMenu("⌚ Schedule")
    .addItem(" Add Week", "addSched")
    .addItem(" Update Summary Tab", "updateTabs")
    .addToUi();    
  updateTabs();
}

function updateTabs() {
  var tabList = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets().map((s) => s.getName())
    .filter((s) => s != "SETUP" && s != "EMPLOYEES" && s != "TEMPLATE" && s != "SUMMARY")
  Logger.log(tabList)
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(tabList)
  var dropDown = summary.getRange("A1").setDataValidation(rule).activate();

}

function include(page) {
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(page).getContent();
}

//ADD EDIT & REMOVE EMPLOYEE HTML 
function addEmp() {
  var page = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("AddEmp").evaluate();
  page.setTitle(" Add Employee")
  ui.showSidebar(page)
}
function editEmp() {
  var page = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("EditEmp")
    .setTitle("✨ Edit Employee");
  ui.showSidebar(page)
}
function delEmp() {
  var page = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("DelEmp")
    .setTitle(" Delete Employee");
  ui.showSidebar(page)
}

//checks for an id# and job code
// if id# already exist, err to checkId
// if job doesn't exist, eff to checkJob

function addEmpRecord(record) {
  let array_target = ws.getRange("C2");
  let array_formula = array_target.getFormula();
  array_target.clear();
  if (!checkId(record[2]) && !checkJob(record[3])) {
    ws.getRange(ws.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1, 10).setValues([[
      record[0], record[1], , record[2].toString(), record[3].toUpperCase(), record[4], record[5].toUpperCase(), record[6], record[7].toUpperCase(), record[8]
    ]])
    var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("<h4>Entry Accepted</h4><p>Close sidebar to continue or add another employee.</p>")
      .setWidth(300)
      .setHeight(125);
    ui.showModalDialog(html, "Success!")

  }
  else if (checkId(record[2].toString())) {
    var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("<h4>User id# already exists</h4><p>Please choose different id#</p>")
      .setWidth(200)
      .setHeight(75);
    ui.showModalDialog(html, "Warning!")
  }
  else if (checkJob(record[3])) {
    var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("<h4>Job Code does not exitst</h4><p>Please choose a valid job code.<br>*Case sensitive</p>")
      .setWidth(200)
      .setHeight(75);
    ui.showModalDialog(html, "Warning!")
  }
  else {
    var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("<h4>Unspecified error</h4><p>Please contact support.</p>")
      .setWidth(200)
      .setHeight(75);
    ui.showModalDialog(html, "Warning!")
  }
  array_target.setValue(array_formula)
}

// checks if an id# already exists
function checkId(num) {
  var result = false;
  var current_ids = ws.getRange(2, 4, ws.getLastRow(), 1).getValues();
  for (id = 0; id < current_ids.length; id++) {
    if (current_ids[id].toString() == num.toString()) {
      result = true
    }
  }
  return result
}

// checks if a job code exists
function checkJob(job) {
  var result = false;
  var current_jobs = setup.getRange(2, 3, setup.getLastRow(), 1).getValues();
  for (job = 0; job < current_jobs.length; job++) {
    if (current_jobs[job] == job) {
      result = true
    }
  }
  return result
}

function editEmp() {
  Logger.log("editting an employee")
}

function delEmp() {
  Logger.log("deleting an employee")
}
```

I'd like to utilize the include("page") function to keep the style, script, and html separate and readable.  What am I missing here?

I think it has something to do with how the data is loaded and evaluated, but don't see how to apply a fix.

When I split apart the code over to the scriplet include function, I looked into using a window.onload eventhandler to re-evaluate the code, but I don't know if that is the best approach with a form.

Comment: Did you write the `include()` function?`function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).getContent();
}`

Comment: Snip of the code from server side: `function include(page) {
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(page).getContent();
}`

Comment: Can you provide your whole script?

Comment: @Tanaike Added the referenced server script to the post. I think this gets you what you are looking for. The only other parts of the script deal with setting up the UI.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to confirm your updated question. Your showing script is the whole script of your current script. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @Tanaike The whole script edited into the OG post as of now, confirm.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed a modification point. Please confirm it. In this case, it supposes that `LOGO` of `<?!= include('LOGO') ?>` has no issues and your Google Apps Script works fine. Please be careful about this.

Comment: Confirmed LOGO works without issue. Thank you. The empty space in the id solved my issue. Sad that I missed it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to remove your current issue of `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'value')`.

When I saw your script, at the top HTML, `<div><input id=" fName" type="text" /> First Name</div>` is used. In this case, `id` is `" fName"`. But, in your Javascript, `let fname = document.getElementById("fName").value` is used.

I think that the reason for your current issue of `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'value')` is due to this. So, please modify as follows.

#### From:

```
<div><input id=" fName" type="text" /> First Name</div>
```

#### To:

```
<div><input id="fName" type="text" /> First Name</div>
```